# Date to String MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Some of the documents in the collection contains Birthday field like given below -

------- birthday : "Friday, February 7, 2014 at 8:03:22 PM" ------

I want to convert to Date 'DD/MM/YYYY' Format.
using python can someone solve this

Comment: Please make an attempt at coding it yourself and return if you are stuck with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use python's [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), all you need to do is specify the structure of your string like so:

```
from datetime import datetime

new_date = datetime.strptime("Friday, February 7, 2014 at 8:03:22 PM", '%A, %B %d, %Y at %I:%M:%S %p').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```